# Functions and function name errors

Tags: function, matlab

I'm trying to write a simple function, *e.g*:

```
function [x y] = functionname (a, b, c, d, e)
```

so I create an m-file called `function-name.m`, with all the variables specified. However, the m-file from which I'm calling `functionname` does not like the name, and insists on calling it the actual name of the m-file (*i.e*, I get the error `not enough input arguments`).

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get around it.  In MATLAB you have to name the file with the name of the function.  Any functions in that file that have a different name are private (not visible to any code other than the code inside that m-file).

Answer (score 3):

The [MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html) states that the name of the file and the function must be identical:

> Save the function code in a text file with a `.m` extension. The name of the file should match the name of the first function in the file. Valid function names begin with an alphabetic character, and can contain letters, numbers, or underscores.

However, what actually matters in practice is the **name of the file**, not the name of the main function declared in that file. For instance, if your file is named `func.m`, but the function inside is defined `function functionname(...)`, you'll need to invoke it as `func()`, not `functionname()`. Try it!

In your case it's even worse, because the file name is "function-name.m", so it contains a hyphen. Hyphens are not allowed in function names (MATLAB interpret them as minus signs), so you are basically stuck with a function that you cannot invoke.

The bottom line is that if you don't want trouble, do as MATLAB wants and keep the file and function named identically.

Comment: Thank you both - however I still cannot get it to work! @Eitan, I have saved the function with the same name as the actual file that carries the function (with the .m, but as a text file, and without a hyphen, as you have suggested). Now Matlab editor likes this (and shows everything in Green) However, when I run it, I still get the same error msg "Not enough input arguments". Are there any rules or 'not-to-do' that I need to follow when I define the function in the text function file? Thank you advance.

Comment: Are you trying to run it by pressing F5 from the m-file editor? If so, that's wrong. You need to call the function externally (for instance, from the command prompt) with all the required input parameters. In your example you need to pass 5 input parameters to your function.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes I was running it by pressing F5, which was wrong, but also there was a folder issue (whereby the function was somehow saved in the place which Matlab did not recognise). Fixing these, my function works now. Thank you!